# Unix file handling removal of Junk chars

Tags: regex, perl, unix, awk, sed

Input file:

```
abc
def^M
ghi
jkl
mno^M
pqr^M
```

Desired output:

```
abc def
ghi jkl mno
pqr
```

I tried:

```
sed 's/^[\^M]$/ /g' file.txt > output.txt
```

ie. all lines shall be segregated with space until ^M [ctrl -m] character.

Comment: Is the control-M (CR) followed by a newline (LF)?  It looks like it.  So you want lines terminated with just newline (not CR + LF) to replace the newline with space, and the lines ending CR LF to end with just LF.  Is that correct?  If so, it's a pity but you can't use `tr` (it would add leading spaces to lines after the CR LF endings).

Comment: yes! I tried tr and it added leading space. but your answer was still pretty good with that! I don't have leading space in data! so I can omit first space chars with '' {null} !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk` you can do:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n*' '{gsub(/\n/, " ")} 1' file

abc def
ghi jkl mno
pqr
```

Comment: sorry but it gave an output with all files in one line!

Comment: I've shown the output I'm getting in my answer. Can you output of `cat -vte file` in your question?

Comment: ohk, when I tried in cygwin it didn't work, but works fine in unix!! thanks a lot!

Comment: On cygwin you need to stop the low level C primitives from stripping the control-Ms before your awk script gets to see them. To stop that from happening you need to put gawk into binary mode: `awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='\r\n*' '{gsub(/\n/, " ")} 1' file`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#PC-Using for details if you care.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. I didn't know about this anomaly of cygwin awk

Comment: I like to think of it as just one more anomaly of Windows :-). It doesn't just affect cygwin and/or awk, it affects other platforms/tools that run on Windows too.

Answer (score 2):

`^M` is usually not the actual characters `^` and `M`. `^` indicates a special character and `M` means it's the 13th ASCII character (M is the 13th letter). `^M` indicates the carriage return character. Looking at an [ASCII table](http://ascii-code.com/) can help. Such unprintable ASCII characters are referred to as "control characters".

This usually means the file has two character Windows-style newlines, ASCII 13 and ASCII 10. Most languages represent this as `\r\n`.

To replace `^M` you can use `\r` or `\015` (the 15th ASCII character *in base 8* which is 13 in decimal).